# Does facebook graph api  provide support for searching Post messages by location?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does facebook graph api provide support for searching Post messages by specific location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to be a multi-step process.

1. Find the places within your criteria.  https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&fields=id
2. Loop thru each of those ids, and build yourself a multi FQL query with up to 50 queries (50 max is all facebook allows) `fql?q=SELECT post_id, message, attachment FROM stream WHERE source_id = {pageId}`
3. Query results, and add to your list of posts
4. repeat 2-3 with the remaining ids returned from the search.
5. display list of posts.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but step [1] returns a list of business places which has an association with coffee. Our intention is to look for all messages posted from a certain geo location (e.g. messages containing "sports" posted in-n-around a radius of 10 miles of San Francisco, CA. Sorry if I wasn't being clear.

Comment: Yes, you were quite unclear about it.  You said SPECIFICALLY "searching Post messages by specific location".  And that's what I gave you for the bounty.  However, because you pull out the "you misunderstood me" card....  location is by Places (aka Page that has geolocation information).  And you wanted the posts for those places.  This is exactly what I gave here.

Comment: For your amended question, the answer is no, there is currently no way to do so with the API as it currently stands.  If this is of high critical value for your business, I might suggest seeing what it takes to become a Facebook development partner.  Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

You can now directly search for posts, photos near a location:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching

It was announced yesterday:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/03/07/building-better-stories-with-location-and-friends/

An example from the docs: 
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=location&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&access_token=whatever

Answer (score 0):

No.there is no way to search posts by location using graph api.please check this for more details https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Answer (score 0):

If there is some [Place](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/place/) object for your location, then yes you can.

Comment: The above post message says using Place it would be possible, but we are looking for searches by location (lat / long) + radius.

Comment: We tried the following query https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=tennis&limit=500&center=34.0522342%2C-118.2436849&distance=10000&type=place&access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAFkJBXNESW3zyHr23pZBH1FpdOqPcMUV43ccnEykQ8ZAw4vzMWltKot089XIszAIbZAZBgXJnp9gdZCvK45tq0LQZANb27OQZDZD&format=json and it fetches all businesses in a certain place. But we are looking to filter messages  by location instead.

Comment: ok, I see. I think today there is no possibility to do this. You can only find Places, Buisnesses, Pages, etc. and then retrieve there posts.